# how to use zencoding haml in vim

Tags: vim, haml, emmet

I am wondering if it is possible to expand shorthand HAML in a Zencoding-like-way in Vim. For instance, I use Vundle in my .vimrc file and have haml plugin installed. So something like :

`#main.stuff>h1.title+h2.subtitle+p|haml`

Is it possible in Vim to trigger above code to expand to :

```
#main.stuff
  %h1.title
  %h2.subtitle
  %p
```

Comment: Why? The reason Zencoding is cool is the fact that writing a selector-like string is much, much faster than writing the HTML it expands into. But HAML is *already* selector-like: there is pretty much no benefit.

Comment: I like the fact that when it expands and it's all perfectly tabbed and it's even faster.

Comment: It is also perfectly tabbed when you Tab it. As for faster... your version is actually three keypress more (>, +, +, |haml, Ctrl-E = 10 keys; vs Enter, Tab, %, Enter, %, Enter, %).

Comment: Yes, in this particular example of code it is less efficient. However, scale a set of navs and uls with their li's and a's, and hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing zen-coding style in vim there is already a dedicated vim plugin called **[emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim)**.

From its documentation:

> Emmet currently supports CSS, HTML, XML/XSL and HAML, Slim languages
>   via filters (see |[emmet-filter](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/5b217264dde398699849a0211bbe1a917d8b2f7a/doc/emmet.txt#L1524-L1533)|).

Of course if filetype is *haml* there is no need to apply filtering. Following expression will also expand to desired snippet of code:

```
#main.stuff>h1.title+h2.subtitle+p
```

will expand to:

```
#main.stuff
  %h1.title
  %h2.subtitle
  %p
```

Comment: You're awesome, thank you. I'm not even in the loop enough to know about Emmet, but the dots are all definitely connected now.